# Django templates syntax error

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

Is there any problem with the syntax in the following code, there is a error as 
`Invalid block tag: 'else'`

```
{% ifequal chat_profile 1 %}
    {% extends "chatprofile/chat_profile1.html" %}
{% else %}
    {% extends "chatprofile/chat_profile.html" %}
{% endifequal %}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[The documentation](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/templates/#template-inheritance) states:

> If you use {% extends %} in a template, it must be the first template tag in that template. Template inheritance won't work, otherwise.

So consider using a design where you can use `{% include %}` instead.

Answer (score 6):

True, you must use extends as the first tag, but you can also pass it a variable instead of a fixed string:

```
{% extends base %}
```

Then you can include a context variable named `base` with the name of the template to inherit from, e.g.:

```
    return render_to_response('my_template.html',
                          { 'base': 'chatprofile/chat_profile1.html' })
```

Comment: Barobes:If i dont have a query set.Could u tell me how to use this.Thanks