# issue with nested if?

Tags: python, django, templates, if-statement, nested-if

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Django templates syntax error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4014156/django-templates-syntax-error)

When i am using **{% if request.user.is_authenticated %}** condition for redirection on this code it throws error `Invalid block tag: 'else'`

```
{% if request.user.is_authenticated %}

{% extends "pages/page.html" %}
{% load mezzanine_tags shop_tags i18n %}
{% block body_id %}category{% endblock %}
{% block main %}{{ block.super }}
{% regroup products by category as products_by_category %}
{% for c in products_by_category %}
......  
         {% for p in c.list %}     
......
        {% if p.num_in_stock == None %}
...
         {% else %}
         {% if p.num_in_stock < 4 %}
...
            {% endif %}
            {% endif %}
        .....        
                   {% endfor %}
......
{% endfor %}
{% endblock %}

{% else %}

<script>
window.location="/stylequiz/";
</script>
```

If i  am using this script then it gives no error

```
{% if request.user.is_authenticated %}
   <h1>welcome</h1>
{% else %}

<script>
window.location="/stylequiz/";
</script>
{% endif %}
```

I think there must be a problem with **nested if** .

Comment: Surely some alignment wouldn't hurt ..

Comment: would you elaborate your comment little bit..

Comment: I think he means "your for/endfor, if/endif blocks aren't aligned, and it's hard to read."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't put `{%extends%}` tag inside `{%if%}`. It should be first tag in the template.

From django docs [Template inheritance](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/templates/#template-inheritance)

*If you use {% extends %} in a template, it must be the first template tag in that template. Template inheritance won't work, otherwise.*

Comment: but if we put it outside if condition then it prints the value which we doesnot want

Comment: @user1896946, in that case you will have to re-structure for templates so that you don't have to put `{%extends%}` within `{%if%}`.